# Unwanted border around input boxes on mobile [html]

Tags: html, css

I've encountered the following issue. When I try to enter something on an HTML site on mobile I get the following border: [image: Yellowish border around input box]

around the input box. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Please input your full code into the post so users may help

Comment: I believe it is the focus selector being activated. If it is not your HTML I don't think it can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the outline from the element.

```
input{
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you haven't provided the code, the issue is being caused by the `:focus` selector. To fix this, add the following to your CSS/ media query for mobile devices as well:

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give `{outline:none}` in style for the html element.

Comment: how's this different from the other answers?